# Unable to utilize Entity Framework after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, deployment

i m using publish option for my project using Entity framework.

the ***'bin'*** of the published folder does contain the dll of project that has Entity framework but the features of my application (using EF) stop working when they Get / Insert Data using Entity Framework .

the error is as follows in my application's File log:

```
02/01/2015 10:25:36 AM|TraceError      |Exception is :The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.|                              |<EOL>
```

Am i missing any thing? ... Please help.

Comment: Are you using SQL server as database?

Comment: This error generally comes when Underlying provider being used by entity framework is not available or not able to load that assembly.

Comment: no i m using Oracle Datatabase ...

Comment: @JenishRabadiya .. yea i know that , but its working all fine when i run it from my local machine, The provider Error comes when i deploy my application on another machine (VM)

Answer (score 1):

This might be happening due to system architecture of processors (32 bit and 64 bit versions of dll).

Try the following steps.

1. Open Inetmgr (IIS).
2. Go to application pools.
3. Open advance properties of the application pool on which your application is running.
4. Set Enable 32 bit Applications (in general category) to True.

I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: i tried, now it gives a different error:
The store provider factory type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory' does not implement the IServiceProvider interface. Use a store provider that implements this interface.
What should be done for this?\

Comment: @Sana.91 Please check out this post http://srinivasvangala.blogspot.in/2012/07/the-store-provider-factory-type.html.

Comment: Yes i did check ... both of the causes are satisfied at my VM. the .Net framework is 4 or later and also ODP.NET client version is 4.112.3

Comment: @Sana.91 I am not much sure about this problem but you can look at this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/default-338300.html#mozTocId893987. If the cause on this post matches your configuration then you can try the solution. Note: Post is targeting the beta version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Oracle database, I assume you must have installed the ODP.NET components. Unless you are using a third party provider such as Devart, which offers direct access to Oracle with its DirectConnect feature, there has to be a middle layer that the developer installs which would translate EF to Oracle. (Even if you used a third party provider, then you must have installed that third party provider on your development environment). Long story short, your VM does not have the provider that your developer PC has. You need to find out if you are using ODP.NET or a third party provider on your development PC, (which, I guarantee you, does not come with any Visual Studio or framework installation, somebody has to install it separately), then install it on your VM

Comment: yes i did install ODP.NET components on my VM , but after installation it gave the following Error:
 The store provider factory type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory' does not implement the IServiceProvider interface. Use a store provider that implements this interface. What should be done for this?

Comment: What version of ODP.NET did you install? Oracle has an article which states this error might be related to the version of ODP.NET. See (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html). Also take a look at this one (http://netdevelopmentmanfreddahmen.blogspot.com/2013/07/c-error-store-provider-factory-type.html)

Comment: The version is 4.112.3 
it is EF Compatible

Comment: As mentioned earlier ... my ODP.NET version nd .NET Framework, both are compatible